# Multiple tabstops to make tab seperated columns line up

Tags: default-settings

I have a file with several columns separated by tabs, the first column needs a 20 tabstop, but the rest are much smaller. This will get me the 20, but "20,25,35,50, etc." fails.

```
vim --cmd "set tabstop=20 nowrap" file
```

Truns out this is impossible to search since "tab" has a special meaning in vim :-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by searching exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
vim --cmd "set vartabstop=20,5" --cmd "set nowrap" file
```

But the following one works too:

```
vim --cmd "set vartabstop=20,5 nowrap" file
```